# Pass variable to the command with regular expression in Tcl

Tags: regex, parsing, arguments, tcl, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass the variable to my regular expression to be used while looping through a list of strings. For example, I have a string which is:
`top/inst/name[i]`, where `i` can take different values of integers.

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $rows} {set i [expr {$i + 1}]} {
    my_command { top/inst/name[$i] top_o/inst_o/name[$i] }
}
```

How do I tell regular expression parser to treat `$i` as a number? It complains that `$i` is a command.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `[`…`]` is serving two different purposes here, one in base Tcl as command substitution syntax, and one for regular expressions as character set syntax. I'm not sure that you want *either* of them at this point, given that the brackets appear to be part of the actual name of something. So you need to be careful.

To avoid the command substitution, you can either insert `\` characters before the `[` and the `]`, or you can use the extended capabilities of [`subst`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/subst.htm):

```
    my_command [subst -nocommands { top/inst/name[$i] top_o/inst_o/name[$i] }]
```

To avoid the other problem, you can either insert *more* backslashes (note that this can make things ugly after a while) or if you are really using regular expressions to just match a literal (sub)string, you can prefix the regular expression with `***=`.

---

It is idiomatic to use `incr i` instead of `set i [expr {$i + 1}]` in `for` loop iteration clauses. It does the same thing, but is shorter and clearer for (human) readers. It's just like using `++i` instead of `i = i + 1` in C or C++ (or many other languages).